# Seo - Importance of href value in anchor tags?

Tags: html, seo, anchor, href

I'm building a FAQ page similar to that of facebook. The question is wrapped in an anchor tag and on clicking the question, the answer appears. I have the following two methods

**Method 1:**

```
<a href="#"> Question1 </a>
<a href="#"> Question2 </a>
<a href="#"> Question3 </a>
```

**Method 2:**

```
<a href="http://example.com/faq"> Question1 </a>
<a href="http://example.com/faq"> Question2 </a>
<a href="http://example.com/faq"> Question3 </a>
```

The anchor tags return false onclick. So is there any seo advantage in method 2 ?

**Note:**
I want all the faq's to be on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use method 1, but make the hash links point to the ID of the corresponding answer element:

```
<a href="#ID-of-answer-1">Question1</a>
<a href="#ID-of-answer-2">Question2</a>
<a href="#ID-of-answer-3">Question3</a>
```

Clicking on these links would jump to that section of the page. No JavaScript needed.

### And...

if you make the IDs to the answer element descriptive (e.g. "how-can-i-help"):

```
<article class="answer" id="how-can-i-help">
</article>
```

...then the links would be quite SEO friendly:

```
<a href="#how-can-i-help">Question3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is a poor way of doing it. You should never have hashbangs as the value of `href`. It should have a valid URL that points to the same content you're displaying using JavaScript. It's called progressive enhancement is a core requirement of accessibility. (FYI, option 1 also keeps the search engines out which is bad  for SEO).

Anyway, option 2 is better because keywords in URLs, including hyperlinks, are positive ranking factors.

Answer (score 0):

Sharanc25,

I might suggest having them as separate pages, as you could customize the title, metas, and content based around the one specific question.  As long as the content is significant, that would result in higher page rank, increase the pages within your website, and allow for customization of each page to focus on the primary question.

Otherwise, there isn't really much of a difference to the search engines here.  The anchor tag and title are probably going to be two of the most influential pieces of information, but if it's all on the same page it's all going to rest under one url, and be indexed as one primary url.